# Please help me remember the expression, 'make a [noun] [to do something]'

Tags: phrase-request

Please help me remember the expression. It means do something in an open and determined fashion, and I believe it starts with 'make a [noun] [to do something]'

Comment: So you want a phrase for "make someone do something"?

Comment: No, 'make a [noun] [to do sth / in/of doing sth]'. I've just remembered while I was writing the comment! 'Make a point of [doing sth]'!